# Is it possible to commit ignored files when creating a tag in Subversion?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I have some folders marked as `ignore` in SVN such as libraries constantly updating in development, but when I create a tag I want to commit them as well in order to keep the full copy of my project, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? Force add them by modifying svn:ignore property.

Comment: @bahrep - *just add*, you can add any ignored object by using it in command-line